# EmailMessage django cc behaving as bcc

Tags: django, html-email, email-attachments, django-email

I am using EmailMessage class to send mail, but I am getting the following issue:

```
People marked in Cc receiving mails as bcc
```

The minimal code to reproduce the result is as follows:

```
def send_mails(subject, html_message, sender_mail, recipient_list, bcc_list, cc_list, reply_to):
    headers = {'Cc': cc_list}
    email = EmailMessage(subject, html_message, sender_mail,
                         recipient_list, bcc_list, reply_to=reply_to, headers=headers)

    email.content_subtype = 'html'
    email.send()
```

```
send_mails(request.data['subject'], html_message, request.data['sender_mail'],
                       request.data['recipient_list'], request.data['bcc_list'],cc_list, request.data['reply_to'])
```

```
from django.template import loader

html_message = loader.render_to_string(
    'send/base.html',
    {
        'product_name': request.data['product_name'],
        'sender': request.data['sender_mail'],
        'body':  request.data['body'],
        'bgcolor': bgcolor,
        'product_url': request.data['product_url'],
        'bg_img': bg_img

    })
```

Also, how to handle if I don't get some fields like cc, bcc in some request?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass Cc in headers as follows:

```
headers = {'Cc': ','.join(cc_list)}
```